# Textarea not filled with all $_GET data, cuts off at quotation marks

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a text area page which is launched from the previous page:

```
$message = $_POST['editPost'];
header("location:editPost.php?msg=$message");
```

The editPost.php retrieves this and fills the text area like so:

```
echo "<form action='index.php' method='post'>
Your Post:<br/>
<textarea name='comments' cols='100' rows='100'>".$_GET["msg"]."</textarea>
<br/>
<input type=submit value='submit'>
</FORM>";
```

The problem I'm getting is not all the data of 'msg' seems to get passed across, or the message gets cut of at the point where it reaches a quotation mark e.g. '

The text I want it to fill the textarea with this text:

> So this is my second blog post for this assignment, I've progressed a bit since my previous post

however it only add this to the text area this:

> So this is my second blog post for this assignment, I

As I say it seems to not contain any more of the string after the quotation mark is reached. Is there anyway around this so I can pass the whole message across?

**EDIT**

I might add, I'm aware a more simple solution would be to retrieve the message again from the MySQL database as that's what I'm using, but I'm just intrigued as to how this works.

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
//$_SESSION['postToEdit'] = $_POST['editPost'];
$message = htmlentities($_POST['editPost'], ENT_QUOTES);
header("location:editPost.php?msg=$message");
```

That is what I do with the data once it is posted from this form:

```
foreach($posts as $postid=>$post)
            {
                echo '<div class="blogPosts">'.$post;
                if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                    if($_SESSION['isAdmin'] == "true") {

                        echo "<br/><br/><form name='adminTools' action='index.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='editPost' value='$post'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Edit' name='edit'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='deletePost' value='$postid'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Delete' name='delete' /></form>
                        </div>";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get it.

`header("location:editPost.php?msg=$message");` doesn't smells good.

**If you simply want to fix the problem use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and when getting the value http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php**

You're getting a post request and then forwarding it using header location. That's definitely a poor way to do it. The problem probably is taking place when you pass the parameter as a query string on `?msg=$message`

Since MVC and alike applications (n-layered apps) is the standard now. You should not do that spaghetti code, mixing html and php and using header as your FrontController dispatcher.

I'd suggest you to use for example, the [SLIM](http://www.slimframework.com/) framework. If you do not want to learn this. You should at least follow the standards described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html).

E.g.:

```
<?php
// index.php

// load and initialize any global libraries
require_once 'model.php';
require_once 'controllers.php';

// route the request internally
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($uri == '/index.php') {
    list_action();
} elseif ($uri == '/index.php/show' && isset($_GET['id'])) {
    show_action($_GET['id']);
} else {
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
    echo '<html><body><h1>Page Not Found</h1></body></html>';
}
```

In short, create a FrontController file that will map to the desired actions (controllers) according to the request without using `header()` to execute specific actions (the exception is only if actually the headers are needed, in fact).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm aware of frameworks to make this type of web coding better however this was a manual exercise which has to be written manually. Your answer given to actually solve my problem was correct :)

Comment: You can still write it manually separating view, controller and model. Like the example I've posted. A framework it's not necessary for that. The thing is, you should not use `header()` to handle requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<form action='index.php' method='post'>
Your Post:<br/>
<textarea name='comments' cols='100' rows='100'>".htmlspecialchars($_GET["msg"])."</textarea>
<br/>
<input type=submit value='submit'>
</FORM>";
```

textarea seems an odd container for it, but that's your call

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem work, I've posted more code from my page where the post comes from.

Answer (score -1):

Use addslashes($message) before passing it in querystring and stripslashe($_GET['msg']) function before displaying it.
Click [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) and [stripslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) for more references.